# Porqué la ruta *new* no funciona en main.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo lo ejercicios del libro Get Programing with Node js de Johnatan Wexler, en la lección 19 se crean varias rutas una de ella es:

```
router.get("/users/new", usersController.new);//this route doesnt work
```

esta ruta se encuentra en el controlador usersControllers dentro de un module.exports junto con otros métodos como *show* de la siguiente manera:

```
const User = require("../models/user");

module.exports = {...

new: (req, res) => {//Add the new action to render a form
    res.render("users/new");
  },
...

show: (req, res, next) => {
    let userId = req.params.id;//Collect the user ID from the request params
    let isAnID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(userId);//THIS FIX in case no valid ID
    if (isAnID){
      User.findById(userId)//Find a user by its ID.
          .then(user => {
            res.locals.user = user;//Pass the user through the response object to the next middleware function.
              next();
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(`Error fetching user by ID: ${error.message}`);
            next(error);//
          });
    } else if (userId == "new"){
      res.render("users/new");
      }
  },
```

Una falla en *show* premitió evidenciar la falla y de momento esta hardcore-ado para que funcione pero no entiendo porqué no lee la ruta *new*.

Ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parece el orden de las rutas resuelve el problema.

Quedando las rutas de esta manera

```
router.get("/users", usersController.index, usersController.indexView);
router.get("/users/new", usersController.new);
router.post("/users/create", usersController.create,usersController.redirectView);
router.get("/users/:id/edit", usersController.edit);//Add routes to handle viewing.
router.put("/users/:id/update", usersController.update,
 usersController.redirectView);//Process data from the edit form, and display the user show page

router.get("/users/:id", usersController.show, usersController.showView)//si esta ruta se coloca al inicio rompe el programa
```

;

Answer (score 0):

porque es un middleware

prueba con esto

```
 router.get('/users/new', (req, res) => {
        return usersController.new(req, res);
 });
```

debes pasarle un request y un response. si te fijas la misma funcion new te dice que necesita parámetros (req,res), y la forma en la que lo llamas no le estas pasando parámetros. con ese código que te envié debería funcionar.

Comment: Nope, el sniped enviado no resuelve. Reacomode el órden de las rutas y parce resolverser pero no entiendo por qué se soluciona de esa manera, de igual manera grx